# If statement in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to display message if user hasn't validated his email

In my controller I have

```
 model.addAttribute("user", auth.getUser());
```

In my template it is

```
 <div th:if="${!user.isEmailValidated()}" class="div-block-10">
                    <div class="user_name" th:text="${Your email is not confirmed!}">Email validated</div>
 </div>
```

I am not sure where am I doing wrong

Comment: What's happening? Do you see some error?

Comment: Your email is not confirmed message is not displaying

Comment: Why do you have text in an expression: `${Your email is not confirmed!}`?

Comment: Here is how to use conditional check https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to translate your message, you will do it like this:

```
 <div th:if="${!user.isEmailValidated()}" class="div-block-10">
     <div class="user_name">Your email is not confirmed!</div>
 </div>
```

In case you want to translate it, use the [fragments of template code](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text) like this:

```
<div th:if="${!user.isEmailValidated()}" class="div-block-10">
    <div class="user_name" th:text="#{email.not_confirmed}">Email not confirmed</div>
</div>
```

And create your key `email.not_confirmed` with the value `Your email is not confirmed!` in `WEB-INF/templates/email_en.properties`. This is just an example.

Note that there's a difference between using `$` (for variables) and `#` (for code fragments). You can't write text inside `${}` statements.